# Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::show_admin_dashbord() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given

Tags: laravel, controller

I face this kind of error when i want to work in a condition.
My controller:

```
public function show_admin_dashbord($id, Request $request){
        return view('admin.admin_dashbord',[
            $result2 => tbl_admin::where('id',$id)->get()
        ]);
    }
```

And my view

```
@if($result2->role=="admin") 
              <li><a href=" {{URL::to('/register-zone')}}"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Register Zone</a></li>
            @endif
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Are you requesting any data in your show_admin_dashbord method?

Comment: use Request as $request = null

Comment: sorry i can't understand ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove request from argument list, cause you don't require and also you can do as `Request $request = null` as specified by @Blue Moon

```
public function show_admin_dashbord($id){
   return view('admin.admin_dashbord'
       $result2 => tbl_admin::where('id',$id)->get()
   ]);
}
```

Comment: now Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::show_admin_dashbord()  face this error

Comment: what's your laravel version?

Comment: Laravel version 5.4

Comment: paste the Route snippet you are poiniting to your controller's method

Comment: Route::get('/dashbord','AdminController@show_admin_dashbord');

Comment: everything seems to be correct 
hit the last method which i think could help `show_admin_dashbord($id, Request $request = null)`